# calling perror() first time success, second time returns ILLEGAL SEEK?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a system call to change the current directory in C++ program and for some reason first call returns success on the PERROR IN THE ELSE and the second one returns Illegal seek on the PERROR IN THE ELSE(using same command and both call to the functions will direct to the else clause). Any idea why? Thanks. I appreciate you guys' help!

```
void changedir(cmd_t& command, int numArg)
{
  char buffer[MAXCHAR];
  if (numArg == 1){
    chdir(getenv("HOME"));
    perror("chdir");
    getcwd(buffer, MAXCHAR);
    cout << buffer << endl;

  } else {
    chdir(command.argv[1]);
    perror("chdir");
    getcwd(buffer, MAXCHAR);
    cout << buffer << endl;

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. "Both commands were in else clause" You only have one `perror` in the `else`. How do you invoke this program? Can you present a testcase? What do you mean by "first" and "second"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I just knew I shouldn't call perror if no error has occured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `perror` if no error has occurred. It will give you meaningless output.

In general, the value of `errno` is undefined after a system/library call, unless that call documents that it sets it to a specific value. This generally only happens when the call failed and the function signaled that through its return value.

In your specific case, don't call `perror` unless `chdir` returned `-1`.

On Linux, [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) will raise an `EFAULT` error if you give it a NULL pointer, but that's not mandated in POSIX ([`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html)), so better check the result of `getenv` before calling `chdir` (same thing for your `command.argv[i]` if that can potentially return a null pointer).

Comment: He really needs an error check after the `getenv("HOME")` as well.  The probability of it returning a null pointer is pretty small, but you never know.  Some idiot could do `unset HOME` in his shell.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  thanks, hadn't thought about that at all. Added a blurb.